# Broadcast error in subtracting Matrix from Grads(…) object

Tags: machine-learning, julia, gradient

I am trying to evaluate a rather complex expression which is average of a gradient and some other stuff as well. I need the value of the final expression to return a Grads(…) object, in order to then update my Params using Flux.update(opt, params, grad).

I am using the following in the code :

```
Julia Version 1.8.5
Commit 17cfb8e65ea (2023-01-08 06:45 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0)
  CPU: 16 × Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
  Threads: 1 on 16 virtual cores
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = code
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS =
```

and packages Flux v0.13.17, Zygote Zygote v0.6.62.

The code itself is :

```
using Zygote,Flux
import LinearAlgebra:tr,Diagonal

struct NeuralAnsatz
    chain::Chain
end
  
function (m::NeuralAnsatz)(x)
   
    return exp.(m.chain(x)).^2
end

Flux.@functor NeuralAnsatz

∇(g::Function,::Vector)=gradient(->sum(g()),)
∇²(g::Function,::Vector)=sum(Diagonal(hessian(->sum(g()),)))
∇(g::NeuralAnsatz,::Vector)=gradient(->sum(g()),)
∇²(g::NeuralAnsatz,::Vector)=sum(Diagonal(hessian(->sum(g()),)))

chain = Chain(Dense(1, 1,relu))
Ψ = NeuralAnsatz(chain)

ϕ(::Vector)=1/2*[1]^2
Ĥ(::Vector, ψ::Function)=-∇²(ψ,)/2 .+ϕ()*ψ()
ε₀(::Vector,ψ::Function)=ψ().^-1 .*Ĥ(,ψ) ## ground state energy 

ϕ(::Vector)=1/2*[1]^2
Ĥ(::Vector, ψ::NeuralAnsatz)=-∇²(ψ,)/2 .+ϕ()*ψ()
ε₀(::Vector,ψ::NeuralAnsatz)=ψ().^-1 .*Ĥ(,ψ)
ε₀(::Float64,ψ::NeuralAnsatz)=ψ().^-1 .*Ĥ(,ψ)

N=10

=rand(Float64,N)
Θ=Flux.params(Ψ)

log∇0=gradient(()->sum(log.(Ψ([[1]]))),Θ)
=[1/Ψ([[1]]).*log∇0.*Ĥ([[1]],Ψ),ε₀([[1]],Ψ),log∇0]

for i in 2:N
    log∇=gradient(()->sum(log.(Ψ([[i]]))),Θ)
    [1].+=1/Ψ([[i]]).*log∇.*Ĥ([[i]],Ψ) ## return grads objects 
    [2].+=ε₀([[i]],Ψ)[1]
    [3].+=log∇
end 

g= 2.0 .*[1]  .- 2.0 .* [2]./N .* [3]./N
```

Stack trace error is :

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::Float64, ::Matrix{Float64})
For element-wise addition, use broadcasting with dot syntax: scalar .+ array
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:591
  +(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64} at float.jl:383
  +(::Union{Float16, Float32, Float64}, ::BigFloat) at mpfr.jl:414
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] map!(::Function, ::Zygote.Grads, ::Zygote.Grads, ::Zygote.Grads)
   @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/JeHtr/src/compiler/interface.jl:372
 [2] map
   @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/JeHtr/src/compiler/interface.jl:365 [inlined]
 [3] broadcasted(f::Function, gs::Zygote.Grads, gss::Zygote.Grads)
   @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/JeHtr/src/compiler/interface.jl:348
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

The error is happening clearly in truing to subtract the 2.0 .[1] from the product [2]./N . [3]./N . The first expression returns a Grads(…) object all good. The second expression seems to return 2-element Vector{Array{Float64}}. No good.

I need to be able to return a grads object from

```
g= 2.0 .*[1]  .- 2.0 .* [2]./N .* [3]./N
```